# Visual Studio 2013, Reset configuration manager settings to default/factory settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have changed settings in configuration manager for one of my projects. Now I want to reset these settings to default settings for this project only. How do I set them to default?

---

[Visual Studio 10, reset configuration manager to factory settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887561/visual-studio-10-reset-configuration-manager-to-factory-settings), this is one of the questions I found on StackOverflow, but It is 2 years old. I think there might be any option availbale now, as new versions of Visual Studio have been already launched in these two years.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you've done extensive customization, there is only a handful of significant stuff in the configuration. What's stopping you from simply changing them manually?

Comment: I have added custom configuration settings, and forgot what was the original configuration settings.

Comment: The linked question refers to the contents of the project file; yours seems to refer to the user settings in VS.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you looking for,

[`/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)

> Restores Visual Studio default settings and automatically launches the
>   Visual Studio IDE. Optionally resets the settings to a specified
>   .vssettings file. The default settings are determined by the profile
>   that was selected when Visual Studio was first launched.